# Is it possible to create a C#/Skype application that displays one of my selected windows?

Tags: c#, skype

I'd like to create a Skype application that displays to the other end of the call one of my windows, rather than what my camera sees. I'd like to select which window and even switch between windows on my machine. I have looked at the API, but there's a good deal there I don't understand. Was wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Skype has screen-sharing capabilities built-in, including an ability to target a specific window. You don't need to write your own software.

Comment: Aha! No, I hadn't seen that before, thanks. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll mark it for you. Thanks!

Comment: Still, I might have a need to do this in my own application. If anyone knows which part of the API does that, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype itself does not provide too many options for its automation. Some program API was announced in the Skype site, but is not yet available (at least for ordinary users). The only Skype API I found was the **`Skype4COM.dll`** in-process COM object. Skype4COM permits operations like management of Skype user accounts, calls, etc. **But most Skype settings are not addressed, and screen sharing is left completely out of its scope**. Other automation techniques should be combined with Skype4COM to achieve active screen sharing.

For better understanding [Remote Desktop Control with Automated Skype](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161451/Remote-Desktop-Control-with-Automated-Skype) might give some idea.

Comment: Understood, I'm not surprised. I just couldn't be sure if I was missing something in the API for this. There were quite a few terms I didn't understand, so I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a read!